# Function to separate each word from a string and put them into a vector, without using auto keyword?

Tags: c++

I'm really stuck here. So I can't edit the main function, and inside it there is a function call with the only parameter being the string. How can I make this function put each word from the string into a vector, without using the auto keyword? I realize that this code is probably really wrong but its my best attempt at what it should look like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<string> extract_words(const char * sentence[])
{
   string word = "";
   vector<string> list;
   for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); ++i)
   {
      while (sentence[i] != ' ')
      {
         word = word + sentence[i];
      }
      list.push_back(word);
   }
}

int main()
{
    sentence = "Help me please" /*In the actual code a function call is here that gets input sentence.*/
    if (sentence.length() > 0)
    {
        words = extract_words(sentence);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Show the code in question, and show your best attempt and explain what _exactly_ is preventing you from solving the problem. And note that the `auto` keyword is a great tool and you should not forbid yourself from using it.

Comment: @alterigel I'm sure it is but the class only allows use to use what is in the material, and auto is not in the material.

Comment: @SeaCucumber24 No, but `std::string` is obviously ok so don't use `const char * sentence[]` - look at the answer you've got instead to see how you can take the argument to your function.

Comment: `sentence.size()` doesn't work for arrays.  try `strlen(sentence)`  or change the parameter to the function to a string instead of an array.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Ok but then how do I create a loop that analyzes where spaces are in the string so it separates the words?

Comment: @SeaCucumber24 https://onlinegdb.com/BJEsSvcH_

Answer (score 3):

Do you know how to read "words" from `std::cin`?

Then you can put that string in a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) which works like `std::cin` but for "reading" strings instead.

Use the stream extract operator `>>` in a loop to get all the words one by one, and add them to the vector.

Perhaps something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> get_all_words(std::string const& string)
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;

    std::istringstream in(string);
    std::string word;
    while (in >> word)
    {
        words.push_back(word);
    }

    return words;
}
```

---

With a little more knowledge of C++ and its standard classes and functions, you can actually make the function a lot shorter:

```
std::vector<std::string> get_all_words(std::string const& string)
{
    std::istringstream in(string);

    return std::vector<std::string>(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                                    std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can only use what has been taught in the class so I can't use stringstream either.

Comment: @SeaCucumber24 If you can, loop `std::string::find` to look for spaces and store the strings between the spaces with the help of `std::string substr`. If you can't use `find`, sounds like you're being forced to play a few bars of the William Tell Overture. Get a byte. Get a byte. Get a byte-byte-byte. Loop your way through the string looking for spaces yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend making the argument to the function a `const std::string&` instead of `const char * sentence[]`. A `std::string` has [many member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), like  [`find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of), [`find_first_not_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) and [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) and more that could help a lot.

Here's an example using those mentioned:

```
std::vector<std::string> extract_words(const std::string& sentence)
{
    /*  Control char's, "whitespaces", that we don't want in our words:
    \a  audible bell
    \b  backspace
    \f  form feed
    \n  line feed
    \r  carriage return
    \t  horizontal tab
    \v  vertical tab
    */
    static const char whitespaces[] = " \t\n\r\a\b\f\v";
    std::vector<std::string> list;
    std::size_t begin = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        // Skip whitespaces by finding the first non-whitespace, starting at
        // "begin":
        begin = sentence.find_first_not_of(whitespaces, begin);

        // If no non-whitespace char was found, break out:
        if(begin == std::string::npos) break;

        // Search for a whitespace starting at "begin + 1":
        std::size_t end = sentence.find_first_of(whitespaces, begin + 1);

        // Store the result by creating a substring from "begin" with the
        // length "end - begin":
        list.push_back(sentence.substr(begin, end - begin));

        // If no whitespace was found, break out:
        if(end == std::string::npos) break;

        // Set "begin" to the char after the found whitespace before the loop
        // makes another lap:
        begin = end + 1;    
    }

    return list;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3sYsaxsbx)

With the added restriction "*no `break`s*", this could be a variant. It does exactly the same as the above, but without using `break`:

```
std::vector<std::string> extract_words(const std::string& sentence)
{
    static const char whitespaces[] = " \t\n\r\a\b\f\v";
    std::vector<std::string> list;
    std::size_t begin = 0;
    bool loop = true;
    while(loop)
    {
        begin = sentence.find_first_not_of(whitespaces, begin);
        if(begin == std::string::npos) {
            loop = false;
        } else {
            std::size_t end = sentence.find_first_of(whitespaces, begin + 1);
            list.push_back(sentence.substr(begin, end - begin));
            if(end == std::string::npos) {
                loop = false;
            } else {
                begin = end + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```